# Run option inactive in intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

First time tried intelliJ to try Java code..I write the code perfectly .But the helloworld doesn’t run..Run button is green but it doesn't work.I tried changing the src mark dictionary in test/resource root.. doesn’t working

Comment: we need more data in order to help. Did you try right click the file that has the main and run?

Comment: i tried to add a picture.. somehow the picture doesn’t attached...

Comment: i clicked  in the right side...there have 2 option edit configuration  and main.. i clicked edit config.there have application and templates..thn click the main class and set this main(com.sun.tools.javav.launcher)

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html try to follow the tutorial

Comment: it works..thanks a lot